# jquery scale a div to the center of its parent div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm having problem with the scaling of a div toward its own center using the .animate feature in jquery. I have a div (width and height defined in a separate css file - 46px and 50px, position is set to absolute). This div sits within another div (its parent), a square which is 52px * 52px in size. What I want to achieve is to scale the child div into its own centre (it has a background image), but so far it only scales toward the top-left hand corner of the parent square div. Any advice would be appreciated.

I have this at the moment,

```
var PARENT_SQUARE_WIDTH = 52;
var PARENT_SQUARE_HEIGHT = 52;
var H = 56;
var W = 52;

function anim(childDiv) {
    $(childDiv).animate({
        height: H * 0.1 + "px",
        width: W * 0.1 + "px",
        left: "+=" + ((PARENT_SQUARE_WIDTH * 0.5) - (childDiv * 0.5)) + "px",
        top: "+=" + ((PARENT_SQUARE_HEIGHT * 0.5) - (childDiv * 0.5)) + "px"

    }, 600, "linear", function () {
        anim(childDiv);
    });
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/84x55e07/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `left:50%` and `top:%50` and the set the `margin-top` to negative half width of child itself, do the same with `margin-left`

**javascript**

```
var PARENT_SQUARE_WIDTH = 52;
var PARENT_SQUARE_HEIGHT = 52;
var H = 56;
var W = 52;
var childDiv = $("#childDiv");

function anim(childDiv) {
    $(childDiv).animate({
        height: H * 0.1 + "px",
        width: W * 0.1 + "px",
        marginLeft: -(W * 0.1 / 2) + "px",
        marginTop: -(H * 0.1 / 2)  + "px"

    }, 600, "linear");
}

anim(childDiv);
```

**CSS**

```
#parentDiv{
    margin:50px auto;
    display:block;
    width:52px;
    height:52px;
    background: #99D100;
    position:relative;
}

#childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url("http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png");
    width: 46px;
    height: 50px;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left:-23px;
    background-size: 55%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0hn050a/